# how to select first and last value of rows and between 5 minutes interval

Tags: mysql, sql

I hava a table with sample forex one minute bar quotes.

```
id,quote_name,quote_date,quote_time,open_rate,close_rate,high_rate,low_rate
"1417","EURUSD","2015-01-01","13:01:00","1.2096","1.2096","1.2097","1.2096"
"1418","EURUSD","2015-01-01","13:02:00","1.2097","1.2096","1.2097","1.2096"
"1419","EURUSD","2015-01-01","13:04:00","1.2096","1.2098","1.2101","1.2096"
"1420","EURUSD","2015-01-01","13:05:00","1.2099","1.2099","1.2099","1.2099"
```

Is it possible to create select statement which will be return 5 minute interval quotes. I mean that it should select 5 rows between each 5 minut interval and return open_rate from first row, close_rate from last quote, and min and max of high_rate and low_rate. 
Is it possible at all? How to do that.

What I know is that how to select min and max value between two dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the five-minute interval is a bit of a pain.  One way is to convert to seconds and divide by 300.  Then, getting the first and last is also tricky.  In this case, I would suggest a trick using `substring_index()` and `group_concat()`:

```
select quote_date, min(open_time) as open_time,
       substring_index(group_concat(open_rate order by quote_time), ',', 1) as first_open,
       substring_index(group_concat(close_rate order by quote_time desc), ',', 1) as last_close,
       min(high_rate), max(high_rate),
       min(low_rate), max(low_rate)
from quotes
group by quote_date, floor(to_seconds(quote_time) / 300);
```